# inset data into table with foreign key and display a single data containing the information of both table

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, model, controller

I want to display the information from table that contains the foreign key.
I just want to display one data from that table and associated information of another table related by foreign key.

Please help

Problem is to display only

Model

```
function getreport() {
   $query = $this->db->get('labreport_db');
   $res = $this->db->query("SELECT labreport_db.R_ID, patient_db.name, labreport_db.Doctor
FROM labreport_db INNER JOIN patient_db
ON labreport_db.P_ID=patient_db.id;");
    return $res->result();
}
```

Controller

```
public function reportDisplay(){
  $data['posts'] = $this->labdoc_model->getreport();

  $this->load->view('SystemAdminUser/labreport',$data);
}
```

Comment: include the code that you have tried...

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **left outer join or right outer join** with **where** clause using join with where condition you can easily display one data from table and associated information from another table..

for example:

**select table1.id,table1.name,table2.address from table1 left outer join table2 on table1.id=table2.id where table1.id="123"**